# ActionBarSherlock, how to get support progress bar indeterminate visibility?

Tags: android, progress-bar, actionbarsherlock

It's possible to set the visibility of the indeterminate progress bar with :

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true / false);
```

But how do you check the visibility of the progress bar?
A kind of "getSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, something like "getSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()" doesn't exist as of now. so,

you could possibly use a flag to achieve the objective.

for example:

```
Boolean isProgressBarVisible = false;
...   
//some code
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
isProgressBarVisible = true;

//and when you set its visibility to false,
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
isProgressBarVisible = false;

//And in your code where u need to perform a check,

if(isProgressBarVisible){

     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing actually... but thanks for help anyway :)