# Check the visibility of the indeterminate ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589989/actionbarsherlock-how-to-get-support-progress-bar-indeterminate-visibility), but because it's 2 years old and there were many SDK updates I'm asking again.

Are there any native methods to check the visibility of the `indeterminate ProgressBar in the ActionBar`?

I know how to make it visible / gone.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true / false);
```

But it seems that this is still the only option to interact with the Progressbar.

Do I still have to use a `boolean or an indicator` in general, to check if the visibility was altered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its still the same. Thats what backward compatibility is here for :D